# Bind datetime to drop down based on Name in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

[image]

I have a table like this and in the code behind i have to show like tempname in a label and rundate in a dropdownlist i have to show like last 10 rundates in the drop down without duplicate name i mean i have to show unique tempname and associated rundates in DDL.how can i achieve this??I need a stored procedure for the same.

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = Common.rundate();
        DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;

        ddl.DataTextField = "RunDate";
        ddl.DataValueField = "TempID";
        ddl.DataSource = dt;
        ddl.DataBind();


    }

}

   public static DataTable rundate()
    {
        DBAccess objDBAccess = new DBAccess();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            objDBAccess.AddParameter("@tempname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            objDBAccess.AddParameter("@tempid", SqlDbType.Int);
            objDBAccess.AddParameter("@rundate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            dt = objDBAccess.ExecuteDataTable("display_rundates");
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: does the `Common.rundate();` actually contain code we can see?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
  SELECT 
      TOP 10
         MAX(RunDate) RunDate
      ,  TempName
  From 
      tblTest
  GROUP BY
      TempName
  ORDER BY 
      RunDate DESC
```

If you need to get TempID then try this ( assumption is that TempID is identity column ):

```
;WITH cteDllLastRun AS (
                             SELECT 
                                  MAX(TempID) TempID
                                 ,TempName
                             FROM
                                 tblTest
                             GROUP BY
                                 TempName
                        )
SELECT 
   TOP 10
     tblTest.*
FROM
   cteDllLastRun
INNER JOIN
   tblTest
ON
   tblTest.TempID = cteDllLastRun.TempID
ORDER BY
    tblTest.RunDate DESC
```

This query for the case if tempID is not unique:

```
;WITH cteDlls AS (
     SELECT 
          DISTINCT 
             TempName
     FROM
         tblTest
)
SELECT 
    TOP 10
     vwLastRun.*
FROM
   cteDlls 
CROSS APPLY
    (
         SELECT TOP 1 
              *
         FROM
             tblTest
         WHERE
             tblTest.TempName = cteDlls.TempName
         ORDER BY
            RunDate DESC
    ) vwLastRun
ORDER BY
    RunDate DESC
```

For the last solution you will need to make sure that TempName and RunDate are indexed, so you have proper performance.

Comment: but i have to show the rundates associated with temp name rundates in a DDL

Comment: In the first query i have to include a column name is it possible??

Comment: If you need to get all columns, then use the last query, it is most accurate, but if you sure that TempID is unique, then use second one.

Comment: Can you please submit error message and confirm version of sql server you are using.

Comment: If i run the lat query i am not getting temp id 1 and 15 i am using sql server 2008

Comment: From the example you have give you should be getting back temp id 2,3,4 which are last run dates for each tempname